# Update page 10 second

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I don't know how to say it right, sorry in advance.
I want to make a page of the site js that the page can be updated every 10 seconds, does anyone have an example?
**that the user can refresh the page every 10 seconds**
I want my user on my site to be able to refresh the page once every 10 seconds

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: I assume what you are seeking is this, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @OshanAbeykoon, approximately yes, but I need to make a ban on frequent refreshing of the page. That you can refresh once every 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make button that will show after 10 seconds so user can but also don't have to update.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
   let button = document.querySelector('button');
   button.style.display = "block";
   button.onclick = () => window.location.reload();
}, 10000);

window.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if(e.key === 'F5'){
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

```css
button {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: And if the user presses f5?

Comment: @elonJS1 I added code that block F5

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
It is impossible to prevent the user from reloading the page, however it is possible to ask if they really want to leave, using this code below, if it after 10 seconds it will not ask if they want to leave, however if it has been less than 10 seconds, it will ask if they want to leave.

```
var r = 0;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
if(r == 1) {
        return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
}
    }

setTimeout(function(){
    r = 0;
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: Almost, but no. approximately yes, but I need to make a ban on frequent refreshing of the page. That you can refresh once every 10 seconds

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible to prevent a user from reloading a page, but i edited the code above accordingly.